# API devuelve un array pero no se muestra en la pantalla

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy intentando mostrar unos tickets en la pantalla desde una APi. Hice la petición con un fetch y la consola me muestra un array con la data que quiero que se muestren en la pantalla.

Hasta ahí todo bien pero los datos del array no aparecen en la pantalla.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> *Edito el codigo fuente:*

```
import React from 'react';
import { getAllTickets } from '../../lib/api';

  class Tickets extends React.Component {
  state = {
  tickets: [],
  clicked: false,
  };
  onclicked = () => {
  this.setState({ clicked: true });
  console.log('helloitsme');
  };
  componentDidMount = async () => {
  try {
  const { data } = await getAllTickets();
  if (data) {
    this.setState({ tickets: data.data });
  }
} catch (err) {}
  };
 render() {
 return (
  <article>
    <section className="container">
      {this.state.tickets.map((ticket) => {
        return (
          <div onClick={this.onclicked} key={ticket.id}>
            {this.state.clicked === true && (
              <div className="boxinfo">
                <h1 className="info">{ticket.fecha_adquisicion}</h1>
                <h2 className="info">{ticket.id_comercio}</h2>
                <h3 className="info">{ticket.precio_total}</h3>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </section>
  </article>
);
  }
 }
export default Tickets;
```

Ese es el método render que hice. Estaba pensando en el undefined "REACT_APP_SERVER_URL:" que se muestra en la consola, podría ser que la función que hice en la API este mal?
Gracias

*edito:*
la petición al API es la siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si puedes comparte el componente completo, o al menos donde este el método `fetch` como lo estas llamando y donde estas cambiando el estado, ¿Estas usando Redux? saludos

Comment: Creo que en tu ```.map()``` te falta un ```return``` deberia de ser asi ```return <div onClick={this.onclicked} key={ticket.id}>``` proba y avisanos si eso te funciona.

Comment: No entiendo, ya tengo ese return escrito si te fijas hay dos return no veo que con eso cambie nada el return que dices ya esta escrito.

Comment: Y no, no estoy usando redux.  He añadido la petición al API por si veis algo que yo no. Gracias

Comment: Porque estás asignando al state un data.data, si ya en el método getAllTickets lo estás devolviendo como data.data.. no será ese el error?

Comment: En realidad puse data.data porque el compañero que hizo el api me dijo que la información esta dentro de data.data y no data pero igualmente si dejo el setstate como data solo, no ocurre nada sale igual que antes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No entra en el `if` del `setState` porque estás haciendo destructring de un array. La variable `data` es `undefined` y por eso no se evalúa a true el if.

La función `getAllTickets` ya devuelve los datos del array no hace falta hacer destructring.

```javascript
componentDidMount = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await getAllTickets();
    if (data) {
      this.setState({ tickets: data });
    }
  } catch (err) {}
}
```

Como el `console.log(data.data)` lo haces en la función `getAllTickets` te muestra la respuesta. Pero si pones un `console.log(data)` en el componente verás que es `undefined`.

```javascript
const { data } = await getAllTickets();
console.log(data) // undefined
```

Mira como usar [destructring](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

[Truthy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) Valores que evalúan a `true` en javascript.

Comment: Cierto el console log de data me sale undefined pero aún así he modificado como dices la constante a const data y nada

Comment: Gracias por los links voy a leer eso a ver

Comment: si pones `console.log(data)` ahora luego de hacer el fix que he dicho que te sale?

Comment: Ahora ya no me sale undefined, me devuelve un array con los datos no solo en api.js si no tambien en el sitio en sí "Tickets.jsx".

Comment: es muy raro. Te entra en el if?

Comment: También tienes que tener en cuenta que los datos no se mostraran hasta que no hagas un click en el componente.

Comment: si quito la función onClick debería ver algo?

Comment: si quitas esto `{this.state.clicked === true && ` sí. Solo deja el jsx

Comment: muchísimas gracias efectivamente quitando el state.clicked ya aparecen datos en la pantalla! Genial gracias de nuevo